# How do I zip an exe and a bunch of dll files together with CPack?

Tags: windows, cmake, cpack

My CMake-based project consists of an `.exe` file and three `.dll`s when compiled with Visual Studio. I want to distribute those files together in a zip: no source code included, no fancy NSIS installers, just the four files in a handy zip archive. I know I could script the operation directly in CMake with `add_custom_command`, but CPack seems a better option. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the files to be *installed* using CMake (with [`install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/install.html)), you can easily leverage CPack to create a zip archive:

```
# Specify to install your CMake targets
install(TARGETS MyExe RUNTIME CONFIGURATIONS Release)
install(TARGETS MySharedLib1 RUNTIME CONFIGURATIONS Release)
...

# Specify the CPack generator for packaging files into an archive.
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
# Specify to exclude the top-level directory from the archive.
set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY OFF)
# Now, add CPack to your project.
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Is it possible to create msi with this

Comment: @AmarnathReddySurapureddy To create an MSI installer file, I believe you need to incorporate one of CPack's [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.26/manual/cpack-generators.7.html) into your buildsystem config. There are plenty of examples online, and in CPack's documentation,  and I believe the more common ones for Windows include WiX, NSIS, and Nuget.

Comment: for python Application is it possible to use wix ?